# Getting AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a data science about sentiment analysis, but when I try the code, an error appears as below

When I am running this code:

```
def remove_links(text):
    # menghapus tab, new line, ans back slice
    text = text.replace('\\t'," ").replace('\\n'," ").replace('\\u'," ").replace('\\',"")
    # menghapus non ASCII (emoticon, chinese word, .etc)
    text = text.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii')
    # menghapus mention, link, hashtag
    text = ' '.join(re.sub("([@#][A-Za-z0-9]+)|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ", text).split())
    # menghapus URL
    return text.replace("http://", " ").replace("https://", " ")
```

I am facing this error:

```
4 frames
<ipython-input-31-cc63b7cbe45d> in remove_links(text)
      6 def remove_links(text):
      7     # menghapus tab, new line, ans back slice
----> 8     text = text.replace('\\t'," ").replace('\\n'," ").replace('\\u'," ").replace('\\',"")
      9     # menghapus non ASCII (emoticon, chinese word, .etc)
     10     text = text.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii')

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Your `text` is not a string, but a `float`ing point number.

Comment: Or a `NaN` (special type of float)

Comment: Please give an example of your data and explain what you're trying to do. Chaining `replace` is most likely not the correct approach.

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: Cast text to str in the method before calling replace: `text = str(text).replace('\\t'," ").replace('\\n'," ").replace('\\u'," ").replace('\\',"")`

Comment: But then it's unlikely to contain any of the subsequent characters being replaced. My assumption is that the input is a mixture of types and not just a float, i.e. the issue is upstream from the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `text` is being recognised as a float, only a string has the `.replace()` method. Likely you could fix this by casting the variable `text` to a string on line 8, e.g.,

```
text = str(text).replace('\\t'," ")...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only given a function and it's output. And you have not mentioned with what text you executed(called) the function. Only if you give the text, we can find out why it senses the text as float.

A blind way to get the output from what you have given is : Just add this one piece of code in the second line i.e the next line after def remove_links(text):

```
def remove_links(text):
    text = str(text)
```